# 2080 TI staying below 35°C rendering in Cycles. Why?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, performance

So I just finished a 24 hour render of a smoke simulation in cycles using Optix with my 2080 TI and I’ve been noticing that my GPU never passes 35°C. I feel like that’s very cool and that I’m not getting the full potential out of the card. Can anyone help with what can improve performance and why the card is running so cool? I rendered at 512 samples with the tile size being 256.

Comment: You could try different tile sizes.

Comment: Maybe something else is wrong, are you sure the temperature reading is correct?

Comment: GPU temperature is hardly a reliable graphics card work load indicator

Comment: Try a higher tile size

Comment: Yes I checked using two different programs. I just am worried I'm not getting the full potential out of the GPU